# Add additional http headers on top of Assignment operation - Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Could someone help me how to added additional headers for assignment operator?

```
export declare class ReqestHeaders{
  method: methods // 'GET, PUT,POST, DELETE'
  headers: Headers // 'get, set, append, delete, has ... etc'
  body: any;
  url: string | null;
}

headerModels: ReqestHeaders;

public getActiveSubscibers= HttpReadRequest.create(`api-getActiveSubscription/activeUsers`) // my implementation
.withOptions(this.headerModels)

constructor(){}

getUserProfiles  = this.http.get(this.getActiveSubscibers).pipe(map((resp: any) => {
  return resp.response.json()
}),shareReplay(1));
```

I want to add "**accesstype**" in **this.headerModels**. how can I do that?

when i moved `getActiveSubscibers` in to constructor , I'm getting error like  **Property 'getActiveSubscibers' is used before its initialization**

if my implementation is wrong what could be the good approach ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's a dumb question, but why not just use an `interceptor` and add the custom header there?

Comment: in my perspective its not dumb question, because the legacy code is like that. Interceptor already used. just for specific scenario i need to add some other headers

Comment: I understand. If I understood correctly I'd try to simply initializate `headerModels` : `headerModels: ReqestHeaders = new ReqestHeaders();`

Comment: Now I'm dumb.. i couldn't understand what you're saying.. could you pls provide short example. Im sorry